# if() then() logic when using Parallel Streams

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a method that I call using Parallel Streams. the call is as follows :

```
myList.parallelStream().forEach(f -> doWork(f));
```

This works as is but I now have a need for doWork to return a boolean signifying whether it failed or succeeded in "Doing Work". Is there a simple way to do something like this ?

```
myList.parallelStream().forEach(f -> 
    if ( doWork(f) ) {
        incrementSuccessCounter;
    } else {
        incrementFailedCounter;
    } 
)
```

The above does not work but i'm wondering if there is an accepted/standard solution to this situation.

Comment: Why does the above not work? Did you miss the block around the `if / else`? Alternatively, you can use a ternary operator: that doesn't require a block.

Comment: It doesnt like if / else logic being a part of the parallel stream call. And doesnt see f as in scope .